# Empty collection initializer for list property results in null

Tags: c#, collection-initializer

When I [run this code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GUAot3), it doesn't initialize `ThisIsAList` to an empty collection as I was expecting... instead `ThisIsAList` was null.

```
void Main()
{
    var thing = new Thing
    {
        ThisIsAList = {}
    };

    Console.WriteLine(thing.ThisIsAList == null); // prints "True"
}

public class Thing
{
    public List<string> ThisIsAList { get; set; }
}
```

Why isn't this a compile error? Why is the result `null`?

---

I was wondering if maybe there was an implicit conversion going on here, but the following attempts produced compile errors:

```
thing.ThisIsAList = Enumerable.Empty<string>().ToArray();
List<int> integers = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
```

According to MSDN documenation on [collection initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx), it sounds like a collection initializer basically just handles calling `Add()` for you. So 
I looked for possible overloads to [`List.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx), but didn't find anything that I think would apply.

Can someone explain what's going on here from the C# spec?

Comment: Servy has the explanation below, but what you want to be doin is: `new List<string> {}`

Comment: Or is `new List<string>()` better? Maybe it doesn't matter. I thought I saw a question today about which of the two options was better, but I can't for the life of me find it now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In section 7.6.10.2 of the C# 5.0 specs:

> A member initializer that specifies a collection initializer after the equals sign is an initialization of an embedded collection. **Instead of assigning a new collection to the field or property, the elements given in the initializer are added to the collection referenced by the field or property**. The field or property must be of a collection type that satisfies the requirements specified in §7.6.10.3.

(emphasis mine)

So since your collection initializer is nested inside of another object/collection initializer the behavior is that it resolves the member it is initialzing to a value, and then adds the relevant items.  In this case, the property is `null`, so that `null` value is resolved, and all zero items in your initializer are added.  If you actually tried to add an item, it'd throw a NRE since you'd be trying to add an item to a `null` object.